# Reconstructing a sheaf from its global sections

Tags: differential-geometry, modules, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on a smooth manifold $M$ with the property that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is a $C^{\infty}(U)$-module for every open subset $U\subseteq M$.
I wonder if/when you can reconstruct $\mathcal{F}$ from its global sections $\mathcal{F}(M)$. Maybe you can define something like
$\tilde{\mathcal{F}}(U):=C^{\infty}(U)\otimes_{C^{\infty}(M)}\mathcal{F}(M)$?

Comment: Presumably you mean to require that $F$ is a module over the sheaf of smooth functions; this is a stronger condition than what you wrote because it requires that the multiplication be compatible with pullback.

Comment: Under Qiaochu Yuan’s stronger assumption: $\mathcal{F} \longmapsto \mathcal{F}(M)$ should be a faithful exact functor (because $\mathcal{F}$ is soft/fine hence acyclic and $\mathcal{F}(M)$ is onto all of its stalks) to $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$-modules – which is probably enough. I think the functor should also be full – and I don’t know about essential surjectivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $M = (—1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$. Define $\mathcal{F}(U)$ to the the module $C^\infty(U \cap (0, 1))$. Define $\mathcal{G}(U) = \mathcal{F}(\{-x \mid x \in U\})$. Then we have $\mathcal{F}(M) = \mathcal{G}(M)$ as $C^\infty(M)$-modules, but the two sheaves aren’t isomorphic.

Comment: Good example! So in this case, is $\mathcal{G}$ a sheaf of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_M$-modules, or not? I’m getting a bit mixed-up…

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!